# Troubleshooting HIP4081

Tags: pwm, noise, mosfet-driver, peltier

I'm driving four N-channel MOSFETS ([IRFLIZ44N](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irliz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535664286325cb)) with a [HIP4081](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/hip4/hip4081a.pdf), and the circuit looks like the following:
[image: H-Bridge driver]

The MOSFETS are driving a peltier module, and the input pins of the HIP4081 are being driven by an Arduino microcontroller. The connections are similar to the ones incorporated by [Open-Source Motor Controller](http://www.robotpower.com/osmc_info/), and following is the associated truth table:

[image: H-Bridge Truth Table]

However, I'm facing a problem in case of "Direction 1". I'm not receiving stable PWM pulses from the output of the H-Bridge Driver. 
[image: HIP4081 Output]

Probing the input BLI and AHI (which are supposed to be LOW), I get the following signal:

[image: HIP4081 Input]

At "direction 0" however, I get a very clear PWM signal output from the IC. I'm not sure how exactly to go about troubleshooting this.

Comment: Unrelated: In my experience peltiers do not like to be PWMd

Comment: @PlasmaHH I see. I referred the [Tellurex FAQ](http://tellurex.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/peltier-faq.pdf), and it mentioned that it's okay to PWM at a low-kHz frequency. If PWMing does degrade the peltier, then I'll probably add a filter before it.

Comment: If you have a good setup and can do some efficiency tests you should do them too, and if there is a meaningful result, might want to write an answer to some question on this site that I think exists and asks about PWMing peltiers.

Comment: PWM'ing a Peltier doesn't damage them, but it gives you really rubbish efficiency. Add inductor/capacitor filter, so that your 4081+inductor+capacitor is just a SMPS, and feed them a steady voltage. Or just buy or build a straight SMPS.

Comment: Peltiers have a high capacitance. It could be that the module looks like a short at the PWM edge frequency so you inject a lot of ground noise that upsets the rest of the circuit. Try to isolate your high- and low-current paths. The currents are also normally quite large, so you may get inductive spikes even though a Peltier module is not an inductor. Try adding some clamping (Schottky) diodes on each side of the H-bridge as the MOSFET diodes are slow in recovery. These are just guesses; a more magnified (in time) picture of the traces would be helpful for a proper diagnosis.

Comment: There appears nothing wrong with your circuit, so I would take advantage of the symmetry.  Try swapping leads on your cooler to make sure it is a symmetrical load.  Then try swapping your FET inputs and see if the problem is on the driver side or the FET side.  Check the polarity of C1 and C2 (and D1 and D2).  If they are correct, measure the voltage across C! and C2 and make sure they are about 11 volts and not too much droop.  You will have to use two probes and the math function on your scope.  Good luck!